# Проверить уникальность поля регистронезависимо yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Пытаюсь проверить уникальность поля регистронезависимо следующим образом:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['model_field', 'unique',
            'on' => 'organization',
            'targetClass' => '\common\models\ModelClass',
            'targetAttribute' => 'lower(bd_field)',
            'attributes' => 'lower_model_field',
            }
        ],
    ];
}
```

где:

- **model_field** - это поле модели, которое я хочу проверить;
- **bd_field** - это поле в бд из модели **\common\models\ModelClass**, с которых я хочу сравнивать, чтоб проверять на униальность, без учета регистра;
- **lower_model_field** - это поле в текущей модели, которое равно приведенному к нижнему регистру полю **model_field**

Друзья, помогите разобраться, что я делаю не так, потому что не работает это.

Comment: Для этого случая оказалось проще написать свой валидатор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все как бы ОК
Единственное почему может не работать это потому что ты включил валидатор `unique` только для сценария `'on' => 'organization'` ( https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/validators/Validator.php#L109 ) если ты его не задаешь `$model->setScenario('organization')` то эту проверку лудше убрать.

Comment: ```'attributes' => 'lower_model_field'```, - вот эта строчка меня интересует. Можно ли так? Не уверен, что так работает. Атрибуты - это, похоже, первый член массива. Или я ошибаюсь?

Вообще, написал уже, что решил задачу собственным валидатором, т.к. встроенный настроить не смог.